# Combine INSERT and SELECT queries to produce a unique ID

Tags: mysql, sql, uniqueidentifier

Background: In a behavioural experiment, bumblebees are tagged with a unique identifier to keep track of their movement. The problem is that the tags are 2-digits only, while the colony can be as large as 500 individuals. This makes it challenging to generate a primary key.

TABLES

(1). Each choice is recorded in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `exp8` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bee_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `choice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hover_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `antennate_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `land_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `landing_position` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` longtext,
  `validity` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=264;

LOCK TABLES `exp8` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `exp8` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `exp8` (`id`, `bee_id`, `date_time`, `choice`, `hover_duration`, `antennate_duration`, `land_duration`, `landing_position`, `remarks`, `validity`)
VALUES
    (1,NULL,'2013-05-14 15:38:31','right',1,0,0,NULL,NULL,1),
    (2,NULL,'2013-05-18 10:27:15','left',1,0,0,NULL,NULL,1),
    (3,'G5','2013-05-18 11:44:44','left',0,0,4,'yellow',NULL,1),
    (4,'G5','2013-06-01 10:00:00','left',0,0,4,'yellow',NULL,1);
```

(2). The start and end date of a tag is recorded in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bee_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `colony_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `events` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `worker_age` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tagged_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=406;

LOCK TABLES `tags` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tags` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `bee_id`, `tag_date`, `colony_id`, `events`, `worker_age`, `tagged_by`)
VALUES
    (1,'G5','2013-05-08',1,'birth','Adult','ET'),
    (2,'G5','2013-05-20',NULL,'death','Adult','ET'),
    (3,'G5','2013-05-29',1,'birth','Adult','ET');
```

(3). A query that distinguish between multiple uses of a tag:

```
select t.bee_id, 
       (case when t.death_date is null then 'Alive' else 'Dead' end) as status, 
       t.tag_date, 
       t.death_date, 
       (case when t.death_date is not null then timediff(t.death_date,t.tag_date) 
             else timediff(NOW(),t.tag_date) end) as age
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.tag_date
              from tags t2
              where t2.bee_id = t.bee_id and
                    t2.events = 'death' and
                    t2.tag_date >= t.tag_date
              limit 1
             ) as death_date
      from tags t
      where t.events = 'birth'
     ) t
group by t.bee_id, t.tag_date;
```

Do you have any tips on generating a primary key based on this data?

Thanks in advance!
Levi

Comment: A primary key for what?  Each bee?

Comment: Yes a primary key for each bee, one that differentiates between bees that used the same tag.

Comment: I might be oversimplifying, but if `bee_id` is the 2-digit tag code, `tag_date` is the date you put the tag on the bee, and assuming you don't reuse a tag in the same day, it would seem like a 2-column primary key `(bee_id,tag_date)` would be a candidate... that would be 2 bytes for the code and 3 bytes for the date ... and you have a 5-byte primary key... which seems pretty reasonable.  Don't "generate" a key, just "use" the natural key you have.

Comment: Thanks Michael -- you're right that would work as a primary key. But how would I assign or associate this key with each new recording in exp8 table where each row is a record of choice?

Comment: I have a couple of ideas I will post, but I need to know your MySQL server version since I may be including some example code that has minimum version requirements.

Comment: That's very kind of you, thanks. I'm running 5.6.12, but could upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to making this more manageable depends on how much refactoring you're in the mood for. :)  Crafting a response to this question is tricky because I'm attempting to stay as close to what you've already got rather than suggest significant overhaul.

This is not exactly a general-interest question but I think the some of the information below might be more broadly applicable.  Some of this reflects techniques I use fairly often to keep more of the intelligence in the database and out of the application that's using the database.

The current structures as they exist do not offer a clean way to preserve relational integrity because there is no base table of "tagged bees."  The tag table, from what I can tell is more like a table of bee-tagging events.  On first read, I thought it was a table where each row was an individual bee, but it looks like each bee could be represented by 2 rows (possibly more, since the structures don't make it clear what the possible data values might be.)

Here are some general observations.

For your `VARCHAR(255)` fields (red flag!) take a look at MySQL's [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html) data type.  There are several columns that appear to support only a small set of possible valid values.  One example:

```
events VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,      /* replace this */
events ENUM('birth','death') NOT NULL,  /* with this */
```

An `ENUM` column is like having a lookup table, without the table, and is good for columns where there is only a small number of possible valid values.  You can't enter an invalid value in an `ENUM` column, and the table will be smaller because an `ENUM` column typically requires only a single byte of data per row to store which value was entered.

Your tables don't appear to have any [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html).  When the data set is small, you may not notice a difference, but as the data set grows, appropriate indexes will make a dramatic performance difference.

Regarding the substance of the question, the "real problem" seems not just to be one of how to select a primary key, but how to be able to assure data integrity so that your subsequent analysis based on the collected data won't be inaccurate.

Note, for example, that your innermost subquery at (3) is not deterministic:

```
t2.tag_date >= t.tag_date limit 1
```

This does not ask the database for the lowest tag_date from t2 that is greater than the tag_date from the outer query, it only asks for "not more than 1 record" and only works correctly if the database happens to return the correct record, which is often likely but by no means certain.  The database is free to return any valid record in response to a query like this, and you shouldn't depend on it always doing what it may be doing now.  This would be more correctly written:

```
t2.tag_date >= t.tag_date ORDER BY t2.tag_date limit 1
```

(The query at (3) is also tricky to understand because you're reusing the "t" alias to mean two different things.)

If I understand correctly, when you're entering observations (the exp8 table) your concern is that the observation be linked with the correct bee, ideally without having to look up the bee in the "tag" table.

If the "tag" table only has birth and death events, you could redesign this as a table where each row represents a single tag on a single bee.  Add birth_date and death_date columns to the table, and then use the id from tag as the primary key, removing "bee_id" and inserting "tag_id" in exp8, a foreign key referencing tag(id).

There's the primary key you were looking for.

You could then dispense with the query at (3) and get bee information related to observations with a simple join between tag_id and exp8 on tag.id = exp8.tag_id.

Create a function to do the lookup based on the date and tag.  This takes the tag code and the observation date, and uses it to find the id of the bee in the (redesigned) tag table.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS find_tag_id $$
CREATE FUNCTION find_tag_id (in_tag VARCHAR(2), in_event_date DATETIME) RETURNS int
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

DECLARE new_tag_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
SET new_tag_id = (SELECT id FROM tag 
                   WHERE bee_id = in_tag
                     AND birth_date <= in_event_date
                     AND (death_date IS NULL OR death_date >= DATE(in_event_date));  
IF new_tag_id IS NULL THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'no such bee'; /* force an error */
END IF;

RETURN new_tag_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

`SELECT find_tag_id('2 digit code','some datetime');` would return the matching id from the tag table or throw an error if there isn't one.

Then, you can embed this function right inside your insert query, which looks like this...

```
INSERT INTO `exp8` (`id`, `tag_id`, `date_time`, `choice` ...
VALUES (3,find_tag_id('G5','2013-05-18 11:44:44'),'2013-05-18 11:44:44','left' ...
```

The value for tag_id will be the return value of the function, and the function will throw an error if no valid bee with that tag on that date can be found.  It will also throw a `Subquery returns more than one row` error if there is ambiguous data in the tag table indicating that more than one bee was alive with that same tag at the time of the observation.

You could go further, assuming the modified tag table with birth and death dates, and impose some sanity on the date ranges in the tag table, with triggers.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tag_bi $$
CREATE TRIGGER tag_bi BEFORE INSERT ON tag FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tag WHERE bee_id = NEW.bee_id AND death_date IS NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'there is already a living bee with the specified bee_id';
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

There is a lot more than you could do to enforce integrity -- much of my work as a DBA involves keeping bad data out of the database -- but this trigger gives you an example of the kinds of things that are possible.  If there's already a bee with a null death_date with the same tag you're trying to insert, that's going to make this table inconsistent with itself with regard to the identity of the bee with that tag on that date; the trigger will block the insert with an error message.  A `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger could prevent inappropriate modifications, for example, changing the death_date on a bee to a date after the birth_date of an existing bee with the same tag.

I hope this provides some useful pointers.  The code requires a minimum of MySQL Server 5.5, so you're fine with 5.6.12.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! The solution is workable but I'm stumped: research assistants rarely use identical tag id's on 2 live bees. The principle here should be to forgive this kind of mistake. I'm a newbie with complex queries, but I think a modification query like this one might create multiple records for multiple live tag ids: INSERT INTO tags_copy (`bee_id`,`birth_date`,`death_date`,`tagged_by`)
 SELECT 
  t.bee_id,
  t.tag_date,
  (SELECT bee_id FROM tags t2 WHERE t.bee_id = t2.bee_id AND events = 'death' ORDER BY tag_date LIMIT 1) AS death_date,
  t.tagged_by 
 FROM tags t

Comment: Can't edit my earlier comment, but the "forgiving" query I think is this one: INSERT INTO tags_copy (`bee_id`,`birth_date`,`death_date`,`tagged_by`)
 SELECT 
  t.bee_id,
  t.tag_date,
  (SELECT tag_date 
   FROM tags t2 
   WHERE t.bee_id = t2.bee_id AND events = 'death' AND t.tag_date <= t2.tag_date
   ORDER BY tag_date LIMIT 1) AS death_date,
  t.tagged_by
 FROM tags t
 where events = 'birth'